# Sharepoint 2013 Foundation - Active Directory import

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, sharepoint-2013

I'm wondering if anyone else out there has the same issue as what I'm having here...

I've just installed Sharepoint 2013 Foundation Preview. What I need to do is import all the users from an Active Directory server into Sharepoint, so they can login to the system and I can assign them access levels etc.

Is there any clear way of doing this without upgrading to Sharepoint Server 2013? I can imagine this has been the same for 2010 also...

I've found no tutorials online that clearly show a set method without messing with PowerShell, even for 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User profile synchonisation is not a part of foundation version (2010 or 2013).

You have to used third-party plugin to handle this or switch to higher SharePoint version (standard or enterprise)